# Search doesn't Filter data

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have the following code to search data from the list. I have used the following code but it doesn't filter records. Here is the codepen [link][1].

Comment: do you want to search on button click or when you type?

Comment: Hi @JuniusL. Yes. i also wanted to move the search in another component `search_page.js` > result in `index.js` page > then `Detail.js`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need two arrays to do the search, the first one holds the original data and the second one holds the filtered data.

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    page: 2,
    itemsPerPage: 10,
    data: cardData.data.Table,
    filteredData: cardData.data.Table
  };
  this.items = createItems(100);
}
```

Search filter function

```
onSearchTextChange = searchText => {
  const newData = this.state.data.filter(
    item =>
      typeof item.first_name === "string" &&
      item.first_name.toLowerCase().includes(searchText.toLowerCase())
  );

  this.setState({
    filteredData: newData
  });
};
```

display values from `filteredData`

```
<List divided>
  {this.state.filteredData.map(results => (
    <div className="col-sm-3">
      <div className="card our-team" id="employeeInfo">
        <div className="card-body">
          <img
            class="pic"
            src={`data:image/jpeg;base64,${results.Photo}`}
            onerror="this.style.display='none'"
          />
          <h3 className="title">{results.first_name}</h3>
          <div className="row">
            <div className="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
              {" "}
              {results.Department}
            </div>
          </div>
          {/* row for Location cubicle Prof  */}

          <Link
            to={{ pathname: `/cards/${results.id}`, state: results }}
            className={`card-wrapper restore-${results.id}`}
          >
            View Detail
          </Link>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  ))}
</List>
```

Comment: demo https://codesandbox.io/s/silent-snow-6odee?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: Men Junius you the Best it works perfect, what if i want to move it to another page and can i add more fields to the filter filter by name by department?

Comment: on a different page you just need the original data and use the passed in value to filter.

Comment: what if i want to add filter by name, by department how can i update `onSearchTextChange `? using multiple textboxes or dropdown

Comment: we can modify the function to handle multiple filtering. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56419688/filtering-data-with-buttons-in-react/56419856#56419856 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58888826/created-multi-filtered-buttons-in-react-but-the-list-wont-display-everytime-i-c/58889822#58889822

Comment: I've also modified the demo, you can now search in ```Search.js```

Comment: Hi @Junius is it ok to add multiple `Search filter function` for multiple textbox search? and how can i list supervisor in a dropdcown filter based on that?

Comment: you can have one funtion for filtering and just pass the key you want to filter with. for example ```searchFilter('supervisor')```

Comment: i want to add multiple textbxes? can you please help me on how?

Comment: please ask a question, I'll answer it when I have time.

Comment: i just did https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59332530/how-can-i-filter-search-result