# How can i filter search result?

Tags: reactjs

I have the following code to display data from `.json` file, i also have the search textbox which search data from first_name field but i would like to search from first_name, last_name and Department, i also would like to use buttons to filter the search result.

When first_name button clicked hide the search result from last_name and department or the search will be based on first name only, the same when department button click show results based on department...

I have the code [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/beautiful-gates-2xkl7)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add more conditions to filter using multiple properties, if you want to filter using all properties do

```
filter.(item => (item.last_name === text) || (item.first_name === text) || (item.department === text));
```

To filter on a key based on a button click, add a new variable to state and on button click set that value to whatever you want to filter by.

```
state : { filterKey: 'all' }
```

on button click update the value to your filter value.

```
this.setState({ filterKey: 'last_name'});
```

Update `onSearchTextChange` to search using multiple properties.

```
onSearchTextChange = searchText => {

  if (this.state.filterKey && this.state.filterKey !== "all") {

    this.setState({
      filteredData: this.state.data.filter(
        item =>
          typeof item[this.state.filterKey] === "string" &&
          item[this.state.filterKey]
            .toLowerCase()
            .includes(searchText.toLowerCase())
      ),
      searchValue: searchText
    });

    return;
  }

  const newData = this.state.data.filter(
    item =>
      (typeof item.first_name === "string" &&
        item.first_name.toLowerCase().includes(searchText.toLowerCase())) ||
      (typeof item.last_name === "string" &&
        item.last_name.toLowerCase().includes(searchText.toLowerCase())) ||
      (typeof item.Department === "string" &&
        item.Department.toLowerCase().includes(searchText.toLowerCase())) ||
      (typeof item.Supervisor === "string" &&
        item.Supervisor.toLowerCase().includes(searchText.toLowerCase()))
  );

  this.setState({
    filteredData: newData,
    searchValue: searchText
  });
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.21.1/babel.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>

<script>

const data = [
  {
    id: "1001",
    first_name: "Alez",
    last_name: "Dara",
    Department: "IT",
    Supervisor: "Supervisor A"
  },
  {
    id: "1002",
    first_name: "Baro",
    last_name: "bara",
    Department: "Accounting",
    Supervisor: "Supervisor A"
  },
  {
    id: "1003",
    first_name: "Tata",
    last_name: "uara",
    Department: "IT",
    Supervisor: "Supervisor A"
  },
  {
    id: "1004",
    first_name: "test 4",
    last_name: "Mara",
    Department: "Sales",
    Supervisor: "Supervisor C"
  },
  {
    id: "1005",
    first_name: "alex",
    last_name: "gara",
    Department: "Sales",
    Supervisor: "Supervisor C"
  },
  {
    id: "1006",
    first_name: "ki",
    last_name: "tara",
    Department: "IT",
    Supervisor: "Supervisor A"
  }
];
  
</script>

<script type="text/babel">

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      data: data,
      filteredData: data,
      filterKey: "all",
      searchValue: ""
    };
  }

  changeFilter = filterKey => {
    this.setState(
      {
        filterKey: filterKey
      },
      () => this.onSearchTextChange(this.state.searchValue)
    );
  };

  onSearchTextChange = searchText => {
    if (this.state.filterKey && this.state.filterKey !== "all") {
      this.setState({
        filteredData: this.state.data.filter(
          item =>
            typeof item[this.state.filterKey] === "string" &&
            item[this.state.filterKey]
              .toLowerCase()
              .includes(searchText.toLowerCase())
        ),
        searchValue: searchText
      });

      return;
    }

    const newData = this.state.data.filter(
      item =>
        (typeof item.first_name === "string" &&
          item.first_name.toLowerCase().includes(searchText.toLowerCase())) ||
        (typeof item.last_name === "string" &&
          item.last_name.toLowerCase().includes(searchText.toLowerCase())) ||
        (typeof item.Department === "string" &&
          item.Department.toLowerCase().includes(searchText.toLowerCase())) ||
        (typeof item.Supervisor === "string" &&
          item.Supervisor.toLowerCase().includes(searchText.toLowerCase()))
    );

    this.setState({
      filteredData: newData,
      searchValue: searchText
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="menubar">
          <button onClick={() => this.changeFilter("all")}>All</button>
          <button onClick={() => this.changeFilter("last_name")}>
            Last Name
          </button>
          <button onClick={() => this.changeFilter("Department")}>
            Department
          </button>
        </div>
        {this.state.filteredData.map((person, i) => (
          <div className="profilecard" key={i}>
            <div className="profilecontent">
              <ul>
                <li>
                  <strong>First Name:</strong> {person.first_name}
                </li>
                <li>
                  <strong>Last Name:</strong> {person.last_name}
                </li>
                <li>
                  <strong>Department:</strong> {person.Department}
                </li>
                <li>
                  <strong>Supervisor:</strong> {person.Supervisor}
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        ))}

        <input
          placeholder={`search ${this.state.filterKey}`}
          onChange={e => this.onSearchTextChange(e.target.value)}
          value={this.state.searchValue}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <App />,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
</script>
```